donde ubico el codigo de SQLite en en una aplicacion de electronJS?
estoy desarrollando una app en electron pero es la primera vez que lo utilizo. Pasa que he utilizado SQLite antes con APIs de expressJS pero en el caso de electron no se donde ubicar las funciones con sus respectivas querys para que este funcione ni el archivo de base de datos. Intente con un archivo de JS donde estan las funciones con sus respectivas querys e importarlas al preload.js asi como llamarlas directamente del front sin el preload pero configurando el nodeIntegration como true. Hasta ahora no he podido conseguir ningun ejemplo que sea de ayuda en este caso.
